# Differentiating $(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}})^3$ using chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

We have,
$$y = \left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^3$$
$$ \implies y = \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$ (Using chain rule)
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac32\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2 -1 }\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$ \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac32\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}\cdot \frac{-1}{x^2}$$
$$ \implies \boxed{\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-3}{2x^2}\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x}}}$$
**What is the mistake in my work?**

[Graphs of $f'(x)$ and $\frac{-3}{2x^2}\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x}}$ are not same](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ze6ramurnz).

Comment: I see no difference in the linked plot for $x>0$. Is the question about the branch for $x <-1$?

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: @user I want to figure it out, throughout reals.

Comment: As I've already said: your result is correct for $x>0$ and is confirmed by the plot. The branch $x<-1$ is an artefact due to the substitution $$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt x}\to\sqrt{1+\frac1x}.$$